# Standard Scala function to replace null with Seq.empty

Tags: scala

I wrote a Scala method like this to replace a null `Seq` with an empty one, so I can concatenate them freely downstream

```
  private def emptySeqIfNull[T](x: Seq[T]) = {
    if (x == null) {
      Seq.empty[T]
    } else {
      x
    }
  }

emptyIfNull(seq1) ++ emptyIfNull(seq2) ++ emptyIfNull(seq3)...
```

Is there a standard library method to do the same thing to avoid writing myself?

Comment: Not much better, but you can do: `Option(x).getOrElse(Seq.empty[T])` - Other than that, I don't know of any stdlib method that handles `null`, we just assume that thing doesn't exists.

Comment: `Option(x).toSeq.flatten` Or just `(Option(seq1) ++ Option(seq2) ++ Option(seq3)).flatten`. Or even `Seq(seq1, seq2, seq3).map(Option.apply).flatten.flatten`